# MVVM Linq2Sql and DataContext

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql, mvvm

Im trying to get my head around how to work with Linq2Sql in an MVVM (WP7) application. I think I understand the basics of MVVM, I wrote a few simple testable apps with this pattern, but I am not sure how exactly should I combine it with L2S.

I dont understand a few things. How do I manage the DataContext? Do I have one per app (how else would I track the changes to the entities and propagate them to the DB)? Can I bind directly to the generated model L2S classes? How do I track changes done on the database? Or should I use the repository pattern for that, which sets of event callbacks?

Another thing, to have the VMs easily testable, I use a system of dependency injections and services for some systems of the app. Typical example would be a service for downloading from the internet - to make it testable, I make and interface and two classes that implement it - one for production and one for testing, that returns dummy data. My question is, should I do that for the database access too? Say all L2S queries would be done only inside this this service, shielding the rest of the app from the L2S altogether. Or is is pointless and I should simply have a global DataContext object / singleton and access it from anywhere?

As you can see, I have many question :) I would love to hear your opinions

Comment: Someone may correct me if I'm wrong but I think you should use the MVVM model on the entities too. I think it is always a good idea to not directly hook your database into your UI, but use ViewModelWrappers. +1 For a good question, I'm starting up on MVVM too and I find it confusing too regarding a DataContext. Btw. I'm not sure about support for Windows Phone at all(Have one but haven't looked in to development yet:)) but do you have LinqToEntities available too, because LinqToEntities looks more promising for the future than Linq2Sql.

Comment: Linq2Sql is available on WP7 (windows phone is actually my target platform), Im not sure about LinqToEntities, I never heard about it, thx for the tip.

I always user VMs as wrappers, but sometimes instead of duplicating all the properties of the Model (and tracking changes of those properties) I make the underlying Model object public read only, so that the View can bind to it directly. But there is still the issue of controlling entire Collections (ObservableCollection) - you cannot bind to a Table. But then how do you propagate additions / deletions to your ObservableCollections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, perhaps follow the repository pattern. If you are  comfortable with IOC follow the same path. I would probably look into mocking your data interfaces though, I find it easier in the long run.

If you are concerned about the db context behaviour it self (eg update tracking) don't... Not from a unit test perspective. That's more a full blown integration test (kind of amusing from a phone app perspective but you know what I mean!)

Remember that there is only one user on your phone and keep the toomstoning in mind.

Comment: So what you're saying is follow the repository pattern, but use an interface for it so I can later mock the repository for testing?

Comment: Just got an idea, how about doing the above, but instead of having all the queries in the Repository (and writing methods for those queries - which is annoying because you have to write it in 3 places - interface, real implementation and mockup) I expose only the DataContext for other objects to use. BUT that wouldn't help with the tracking of insertion/deletion... Well, just a thought then

Comment: Hmm, I thought finding a tutorial on-line for that scenario would be easy! This one is the kind of thing I mean: [ http://scottdepouw.com/blog/let-rsquo-s-unit-test-some-linq-to-sql/ ] if anyone has a more specific example...?

Comment: Check this out: http://moqalate.codeplex.com/ [disclaimer!! i have not used it yet...]

Comment: a good TDD article... http://codingsolutions.blogspot.com.au/2010/03/windows-phone-7-tdd-kata-using-mvvm-and.html

Comment: Thanks - do you feel inspired to write a tutorial now?! (I am sure they are out there, just couldn't see it easily)